# PyCharm - Django settings honoured in run config but not in python console

Tags: python, django, pycharm

While setting up my django project in PyCharms I am having trouble configuring the python shell for django. My project structure is as follows:

```
- mysite_root
    - deployment
        - ...ansible files
    - mysite
        - __init__.py
        - manage.py
        - mysite
            - __init__.py
            - settings.py
            - local_dev_settings.py
        - app1
            - __init__.py
            - ...other files
        - app2
            - __init__.py
            - ...other files
```

The Sources root is set to `mysite_root/mysite`
My Run/Debug configuration has the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.local_dev_settings` & it works perfectly.
Inside the Project settings under `Language & Frameworks --> Django` the configuration is as follows:

```
- Django project root -- <path to mysite_root/mysite>
- Settings -- mysite/local_dev_settings.py
- Manage script -- manage.py
- Environment variables -- DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.local_dev_settings
```

Now, while launching the Python Console or Manage.py Tasks via Tools, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/utkarsh/.venvs/mysite/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2885, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-1-4578708c9793>", line 5, in <module>
    if 'setup' in dir(django): django.setup()
  File "/Users/utkarsh/.venvs/mysite/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/Users/utkarsh/.venvs/mysite/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/utkarsh/.venvs/mysite/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/utkarsh/.venvs/mysite/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/Users/utkarsh/.venvs/mysite/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'mysite.local_dev_settings'
```

**Edit: Found the Resolution for the issue**
Please refer answer below for the resolution of this problem.

Comment: I think I may have misread your question... in the same dialog as I had in my answer, there is an environment variables section, try setting your settings module there (add an env variable called DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE and set that to your settings)

Comment: Just figured it out. The issue was the both Content & Sources root were included & hence `mysite_root/mysite` came before `mysire_root/mysite/mysite` due to which pycharm failed in loading the settings, even though it should have looked in the latter package as well.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: No worries, you should consider adding an answer to your own question, it may help future readers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the resolution myself.

The issue was that under <kbd>Build, Execution, Deployment</kbd> -> <kbd>Console</kbd> -> <kbd>Django Console</kbd> both Content & Sources root were included & hence `mysite_root/mysite` came before `mysire_root/mysite/mysite` due to which PyCharm failed in loading the settings, even though it should have looked in the latter package as well. Upon disabling the option `Add Contents root to PYTHONPATH`, everything started working fine. :)